# Unable to change value of variable having a element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to iterate through some elements in a div and change a value using jQuery. Here's my code which doesn't seem to be working. Kindly highlight my errors.

```
var f=$(".Midfeilders img:first"); // used to store 1st element in a variable ...
```

Later on in the code what I wish to do is

```
{
  f.attr("src",s);
  f=f.next() or f=f.nextSibling;
}
```

Here's the error, this doesn't seem to change the value of src

When I do something like this,

```
$(".Midfeilders img").attr("src",s);
```

The code runs perfectly, but if I use the above approach I can't go to the next element.
I suspect its the  f.attr("src",s) which seems to be the issue.

Comment: Are you in the right scope, probably `f` is undefined ?

Comment: Hi adeneo, no variable f has been declared global right in the begginning.

Comment: Open up the console (F12) and look for errors.

Answer (score 0):

`f.next()` doesn't simply move f to the next element.  it returns the next element. So you would need to do something like this:

```
f = f.next();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir i tried you solution, But i feel the problem lies in                                                     f.attr("src",s);                                                     as the image isn't changeing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure you are understanding the way you iterate over elements with jQuery.

I'm going to use this HTML sample -

```
<img src="" />
<img src="" />
<p></p>
```

And an [`$.each` command](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to demonstrate -

```
$('img').each(function(index,elem){
  // The $(this) variable will be the relative element 
  // that the loop is currently iterating over
  $(this).attr('src',SOME_URL); 

  // on the first iteration, this variable will be the second img element.
  // on the second iteration, this variable will be the paragraph element
  var otherElement = $(this).next();
});
```

Comment: Hi Lix, I wish to iterate only 1 step at a time only on occourance of an onclick event                                                            PS-A small overview I have 5 images arranged horizontally and i want to change the image on click of a text, However if i were to use your approach, i would have to change all the images at once which i do not desire.Hence i used the .next() function, But the problem here seems to be in the .attr()  function, as it doesn't seem to change the image

Comment: I don't think it is the `attr` function that is the issue. It is most likely the selector that it is used with. Try using `console.log()` to debug a bit more and see what elements you are actually using.